# r - intersection of 3D objects

Tags: r, polygon, line, intersection

How can an intersection of 3D object with 3D object be done in R, for example a 3D line with 3D polygon?

Saw that "sf" provides some possibilities but didn't get the desired result.

What was accomplished:

```
library(dplyr)
library(sf)

# create 3D polygon
pol1 <- data.frame(lon = c(6,6,6,6,6),
                   lat = c(3,1,1,3,3),
                   alt = c(2,2,4,4,2)) %>% 
st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat", "alt"), dim = "XYZ") %>% 
summarise(do_union = FALSE) %>% 
st_cast("POLYGON")

#create 3D line
lns1 <- matrix(c(5,8,2,2,2,4), ,  3) %>% st_linestring(dim = "XYZ")

# trying to find the point where they intersect
>st_intersection(lns1, pol1)
GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY
```

Comment: Is what you've tried consistent with intersections ignoring the 3rd dimension and doing only 2D geometry on the X and Y coordinates? Because I suspect that's the limits of its capabilities.

Comment: @Spacedman the code works for 2D objects. I thought "sf" should be able to handle 3D operations since there is a possibility to define 3D objects with it. For example an intersection between a 3D line and another 3D line is done correctly. Could there be an alternative for 3D line - 3D polygon intersection ?

Comment: Not sure why this question was closed, I think it is a relevant one. `{sf}` implements OGC's [Simple Feature standard](https://portal.ogc.org/files/?artifact_id=25355). In section 6.1.2.5 of the document it states: `Spatial operations work in the "map geometry" of the data and will therefore not reflect z or m values in
calculations (e.g., Equals, Length) or in generation of new geometry values (e.g., Buffer, ConvexHull, Intersection).` To my understanding that means as long as `{sf}` conforms to the standard, spatial operations will always be calculated in map geometry.